# Cannot connect to Sqlserver from python script in windows XP

Tags: python, sql-server, windows, windows-xp, pymssql

I am using a windows XP machine that is using Microsoft SQl Server Enterprise Edition version 8.00.194, SQL-DMO version: 8.00.02 and ODBC version : 03.52.0000. I have another database of MySql on some other machine in the same network and I want to retrieve the data from that database to my XP machine's Sqlserver database. For this purpose I am trying to check whether I can connect to the local machine with my following python script (I use the pymssql library for this purpose):

```
import pymssql

con1=pymssql.connect(server="localhost:1433",user="XXXX",password="XXXX",database="XXXX")
print con1
con1.close()
```

I have purposefully removed the original username, password and db name. After running the above script I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\py_script_data_1st\1.py", line 9, in <module>
    con1=pymssql.connect(server="localhost:1433",user="xxxx",password="xxxx",database="xxxx")
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 636, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10178)
OperationalError: (20009, 'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist\nNet-Lib error during Unknown error (10061)\n')
```

I have searched extensively but did not get any working solution for that error. What I got was to open the port 1433. I have opened the sqlserver.exe instance in my firewall by following the instructions given https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/841251

When I do telnet on port 1433 by using:

```
telnet localhost 1433
```

I get error that says could not connect to port 1433.

I would also like to add that the database on which I am working is of a library system. There are two machines on which issues/returns trasactions of the book takes place. So the other machine (which is also a windows XP machine) connects to the server machine using a software that uses netbios-ssn for the communication. I found this fact by using `netstat` command. Here is the output of that command:

```
TCP    issue:netbios-ssn      192.168.48.45:2211     ESTABLISHED
TCP    issue:netbios-ssn      192.168.48.48:3456     ESTABLISHED
```

I am extremely confused about these facts. I don't understand how can other machine access server's database using netbios-ssn port?

So, I have effectively two questions and solution to any one of them can help me out.

1. What is the solution for the problem of the python script ?
2. If the first problem cannot be solved, how can I achieve the connection to the database using netbios-ssn port?

Please help and feel free to ask any further information if you want.

Comment: Did you ever fix this problem using pymssql? If so it'd be nice to put the answer :)

Comment: @SaulCruz, No we didn't find any solution. As time was running out, we had to manually proceed with our queries and port it to other DB.